# Cosa significa "zippo" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto questa lunghissima frase:

> Le ferrovie pagano il viaggio – sola andata – ai workers e al foreman, ma non ai ritardatari, e siccome il viaggio costa almeno sessanta dollari, e Diamante non ne ha piú nemmeno uno, ecco che lo zio Agnello, il generoso zio Agnello che ha pagato il viaggio in America a questo ingrato pezzente, che ha supplicato la bontà del boss per lui, che gli ha ottenuto un posto in squadra nonostante la sua età, che ha mentito per lui, assicurando che ha quattordici anni ed è forte e robusto, mentre non ne tiene manco dodici e ne dimostra otto ed è uno **zippo** striminzito, ’nu cardiglio – ecco che lo zio Agnello ingrogna veramente – m’aggio ’ccattatu ’stu zenzuso appezzentito, n’auta vocca a sfama’ a Novarco, lui che fatica come un ciuccio per pensare alla sua famiglia – ma i’ te lu dicu a tte, zelòfreco perocchioso, stamm’a senti’ nun aggio faticatu pe’ acquista’ gli quatrini pe’ fatte gudenno della robba mea, si nun te trovi ’nu giobbo te scaso, te sguarro, te fazzo zompa’ l’ogne de fame – e di nuovo un ceffone da far ronzare le orecchie – campamorto, te puzzi screfunna’…

Qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare cos'è uno "zippo" in questo contesto? Nei dizionari che ho consultato ho visto che "zippo" significa "accendino", ma questo non ha senso in questo contesto. Immagino si tratti di un termine di origine dialettale.

Comment: Considerato che "cardiglio" dovrebbe indicare un cardellino cioè un piccolo uccello, credo che "zippo" indichi in qualche modo una persona minuscola. Ho però  trovato questa pagina https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080924125223AA1ZDBn&guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAIPMf8SlWBkwJ2B95NNUFHeIZ2MuqBA9Fh36lPP-YeiY3nD_ca8zBvJj-C3AW9BizE_gjge6lnvA5grzTo0BpkxgnmIJ0E5kuteXs8gjTX8_ASkhnIiK41h-ivw2W7wMo6YfjL-ylMwYxoXaySH4uhqqkhGlACs_FEHRzcmEhvE3 in cui "zippo" sembra significare "palo" (= persona molto magra)

Comment: A orecchio, direi che sia una variante di [zeppo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/zeppo2), appunto nel senso di persona molto esile.

Comment: @DaG: I personaggi sono originari di Minturno, quindi penso che sia quello che dici nel tuo commento.

Answer (score 3):

"Zippo" nei dialetti dell'alto Casertano è un bastoncino sottile e dritto, che all'occorrenza può essere usato per essere infilato in una cavità  o in uno spazio stretto per pulire o recuperare qualcosa, per esempio per pulire una bottiglia, la canna di un fucile o per infilarlo nel muro per farne una meridiana o per appenderci qualcosa, oppure per farne uno spiedo. Espressioni tipiche "È sicco comme nu zippo" (magro come un bastoncino) "Addó arrivammo piantammo ru zippo" (dove arriviamo ci fermiamo e lasciamo un bastoncino nel terreno per segnale, per riprendere il lavoro da lì successivamente). Voce verbale derivata: 'nzippà = infilare.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE nel suo [decimo anniversario](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1489/707)!

Comment: Confermo, anche io, conoscendo il napoletano, avrei detto che significa 'zeppo, bastoncino'. Anche a Napoli si dice una cosa simile: 'Addó arrivammo, llà mettimmo 'o spruoccolo' (*spruoccolo* è lo stesso, *zeppo, bastoncino*). Ma, appunto, i personaggi sono di Minturno, e anche da quello che leggo del brano riportato dal libro di Melania Mazzucco, non si tratta di napoletano standard, ma dialetto locale.

Comment: A Napoli *zeppo* si usa, famoso è *lo zeppo al contatore*, truffa per non pagare la bolletta mettendo, appunto, uno zeppo che lo blocca.

Answer (score 2):

In questo [dizionario dialettale](https://dialettitaliani.it/wiki/Zippo) ho trovato invece che *zippo* in dialetto Barese vuol dire:

> Zippo: Rametto, ceppo di legno

Come riportato nei commenti alla domanda, penso che *zippo* voglia dire persona minuta e molto magra, come un rametto o stecco.

Comment: Io non posso vedere questo su Garzanti, vedo soltanto "zippare". "Amer." significa che è di origine americana?

Comment: Su [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/zippo) trovi che il termine appartiene allo slang anche in Inglese britannico

Comment: Quella voce su _zippo_ è tratta dal dizionario inglese-italiano; mi sembra improbabile che in un romanzo italiano di ambientazione locale si usi un termine inglese (per giunta non classico, ma recente e informale).

Comment: @DaG: Tuttavia, questi personaggi abitano a New York e, per esempio, usano i termini "workers", "foreman" e "boss". Mi sembra però più probabile che si tratti di una variante di "zeppo", come tu hai suggerito.

Comment: Da Barese confermo: per zippo si intende un paletto, o un ramo, o un ceppo di legno solitamente lungo e sottile.

Answer (score 0):

Lo zippo è la coda del cucchiaio di legno che si usa maggiormente per rivoltare le fave che si cuociono nella pignata di coccio. È un cucchiaio dalla coda a punta e la testa a paletta rotonda, lunga  circa 35/40 cm.

Comment: Scusa, @Nicola, ma dove si usa "zippo" con questo significato?

Comment: Grazie e benvenuto! Riesci per caso ad aggiungere un riferimento, anche solo con un link a una pagina internet che usa la parola con questa accezione?